# Устаревшие аналоги некоторых современных выражений

Tags: словосочетания

Мне приходилось слышать, что устойчивое выражение «честно говоря» появилось где-то веке в ХХ на основе старинного «по чести сказать», которое и в начале двадцатого века было больше в ходу. Если кто может, составьте, пожалуйста, подборку изменившихся со временем вводных словосочетаний с их первоначальными вариантами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вам надо Виноградова, "Историю слов" почитать. Список такой вряд ли кто составит, да и вопрос не совсем ясный.

Сам ваш пример уже вызывает вопросы. "По чести говоря" в нацкорпусе до 1917 г. встречается 1 раз - у Чехова. "Честно говоря" - тоже 1 раз. "Честно сказать" и "по чести сказать" - по 4 раза. Полный паритет.

Тут скорее надо говорить о замене инфинитива "сказать" на деепричастие "говоря". А сами формы "по чести" и "честно" с обоими вариантами считать эквивалентными.